# Updated version of file is not applied

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, file, carrierwave, updates

I have file, which should be updated after updating instance attributes
It looks like this:

**controller.rb**

```
def update 
  if UpdateNewspaperDesign.new(newspaper_design, newspaper_design_params).call
    #render response
  end
end
```

and

```
class UpdateNewspaperDesign
  def initialize(newspaper_design, params)
    @newspaper_design = newspaper_design
    @params = params
  end
  def call
    newspaper_design.assign_attributes(params)
    File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'tmp', "newspaper-design-#{Time.now.to_i}.css"), 'w') do |file|
      file.write(css(newspaper_design))
      newspaper_design.css = file
    end
    newspaper_design.save
  end
  private
  attr_reader :newspaper_design, :params
  def css(newspaper_design)
    NewspaperDesignCssCompiler.new(newspaper_design).call
  end
end
```

And then I include css in layout

```
= stylesheet_link_tag newspaper.design.css_url, media: 'all'
```

As I see in console: css url is updated, but the url, which is inserted in layout - is not update.

Comment: Declaring `attr_reader :newspaper_design, :params` in private is strange if not an anti-pattern since instance attributes are private in Ruby.

Comment: Its also pretty unclear what you are trying to do - if you are trying to let the user update the sites CSS you should be aware that the Rails asset pipeline is meant to compile assets at deploy time - not per request as that would be really slow. So if you want the user to able to modify the `application.css` or any of the files linked with the asset helpers you would have to trigger a recompile. However its not a very good idea since you loose proper version control. Trust me, I have maintained  large sites where the editors copy paste all kinds of crap CSS from the interwebs...

Comment: @max user is updating design attributes for example - color, than I recompile css manually, add this css to file and upload it.
Than this css is included in layout file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace **File** with **Tempfile**
- this is how I fixed it